# Why is type checking expensive?

Tags: performance, types, casting, computer-science

I've heard many anecdotes that a large problem with dynamically typed languages is that type checking is very slow. Why is it slow though? What is the computer science rational that using runtime assigned types that may change cause large slowdowns in computational efficiency?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dynamically typed languages must perform type-checking *while* code is running. Although they can sometimes be compiled, they need to cut many corners for reasonable performance. One big drawback of checking at runtime is that if a type fails to be valid, the interpreter can only throw exceptions or stop execution.

So they often try to coerce types to prevent exceptions, even when it may be undesirable. In python, it isn't uncommon to discover that a simple division by whole integers means that my user output is suddenly full of '2.0' because I didn't explicitly cast back into `int`.

The computer science rational is that type-checking is an extremely heavy algorithm. For every function you call, all the types involved must be validated (or coerced which may be another function call), and type information must be updated afterwards. At runtime you can only afford to have a simple type system and very little optimization. A compiler by comparison can exploit even a weak type system to optimize your inefficient algorithms away.

---

It's very common for statically-typed languages to be compiled, and dynamically-typed languages to be interpreted. This is because if a language is being designed for a compiler, it's a no-brainer to give the responsibility of type-checking to the compiler so that your code will be more optimal and won't need to manage typing at runtime. The less you need to carry at runtime, the faster code will execute.

Ultimately, this means languages designed for interpreters can't afford the level of typing a compiler can. In addition to having less freedom to exploit type information to optimize - strike 1 to performance - they must carry and modify type information at runtime - strike 2. The weaker type system also introduces many type safety bugs.

Naturally, there are also numerous cases where weak typing is desirable. Dynamic languages often take the role of scripting; they're quick to code, easy to interpret, and can be ported to new platforms faster than a compiler! This makes them invaluable for gluing very different systems together. One script can interact with the operating system and many programs on it to schedule a daily download of all the latest cat videos from your favourite website.

As always, I highly recommend that you have a dynamic language and a static language in your repertoire. It's invaluable to have access to the guarantees of strong typing and access to the ease of weak typing. Be a code omnivore :)

Comment: This is a comprehensive and well thought out answer. Thank you for putting this together, appreciate it!